# Suspicious/fake users?

Tags: discussion, new-users, users

I see a lot of users that has 1 in rep, asks a question, then never to return.

What I'm **suspecting** that these are existing users, that don't want their rep to go down by asking "silly questions". To be honest I've stopped answering them, which is bad if there are actual new users there. They tend to not bother marking answers or upvote.

What's the policy for this? Is there any way you can restrict this, if it is the case?

At least in my view, it's sort of degrading the site.

Comment: As far as I know are post bans for returning bad questions not restricted to accounts, but to IP addresses as well. That will making new accounts for question useless.

Comment: Don't let it depend on who the user is. Is it really a silly, bad-written question? Then act appropriately.

Comment: As long as they aren't used to commit voting fraud or otherwise get around a system restriction, there is nothing wrong with having multiple accounts.

Comment: I think that it is bad policy not to answer new users questions, whatever the reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the things we want to be is a place where people can come, ask one question and never return. It's not the totality of what we want to be, but we shouldn't be stopping someone who perhaps is trying programming for the first time and has a question. The fact that they don't return could be for any number of reasons, perhaps they realise they don't like programming after all. However, **we shouldn't be the place that turns them off programming**. If anything we want to be the place that welcomes them with open arms and shows them how rewarding programming can be - when it's done correctly.

If you don't like the look of a question then just go back to the list and pick another one. After all it's not as if we're short of questions.

Comment: OFC we shouldn't turn out to a "trolling site", so we scare off actual new users, and in worst case turns them away from programming. That's not what I ment in my post. Everyone deserves an answer to a problem, and we should absolutely not scare new users away. The share number of them, makes me wonder.

Comment: @Stian. What I mean is that we don't want to restrict these questions any more than we do now with the quality filters etc. we currently have in place. Actually I don't think we can.

Comment: +1 I fully understand that. I'm marking your post as an answer. The sad thing though, if people like myself, are starting to be reluctant to answer, particulary questions that require big answers . Guess I just have to live with it, and don't care ;)

Comment: @Stian.: "Everyone deserves an answer": Actually no, though if they showed minimal respect by formulating a tolerably good question (it need not yet be good, even a hint of promise might work as long as learning seems to occur) and trying to follow the sites guidelines (or at least show an inclination to get their things together), they will get good reception (which means others spend their time trying to answer their question, hint/edit to improve it, and might give lots of other good advice: Upvotes must be earned by the posts merit).

Comment: "We want to be the place that welcomes them with open arms and shows them how rewarding programming can be" if they are able to ask an on-topic, researched, and somewhat decently formulated question, and have a general understanding that SO is not just another forum or help site. Otherwise we first want to teach them the basics and expected quality standards of SO, and if they are unable or unwilling to follow them, we definitely do _not_ want them to feel welcome in any way.

Comment: @l4mpi - Yeah, perhaps I should have made that point explicitly ;)

Answer (score 11):

When you answer a question, you're not only answering for the questioner, but also for other people that have the same issue. I wouldn't judge whether or not you answer a question because of the questioner's reputation level, but that of the question quality. If it's a silly question, don't answer it, even if it's from a 20k user. If it's a good question, answer it even if it's from a 1 rep user.

Comment: Is that really the case? We are answering a question, yes; but are we really helping the user or people with the same issue? I'm fairly new to SO, but from my short experience (and maybe I got the wrong impression), most of those questions: a) have been asked and answered before (so it's a duplicate that won't really benefit future users); or, b) are so specific to the user's application/problem that they won't be useful for anybody else.

Comment: We have duplicates only because we only want to answer each question once, and it would be a bad site if you couldn't get the answer to a question that has already been asked, so of course people should be able to get an answer from an answer to someone else's question. Also note that we flag problems caused by typos or no reproducible as off-topic here since they won't help future users.